# Closure Compiler Warning on Object.keys

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
var ObjectLength = Object.keys(SomeObject).length;
```

I need the number of keys in the object. With this line, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING - actual parameter 1 of Object.keys does not match formal parameter found : (Object|null)
```

What do I need to change in my code to remove the warning?

Comment: What is SomeObject?

Comment: Are you passing in a valid object as a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closure-Compiler believes that `SomeObject` could potentially be `null` and is warning you about this. Ensure the value passed in can never be null:

```
var ObjectLength = Object.keys(SomeObject || {}).length;
```